# What kind of SSD do I have in my 2017 27" iMac?

Tags: imac, ssd

Back in 2017 I purchased a 27" "Core i7" iMac, and opted to get the storage upgrade giving it a 500 GB SSD instead of a hard drive or fusion drive. I'm now considering upgrading the storage, but I'm not sure if the drive is a conventional SATA SSD or a "blade SSD" (to use iFixIt.com's terminology) that uses a proprietary connector, which I understand to be similar to but different from NVMe. The upgrade procedure is quite different depending on which it is.

How can I tell what kind of SSD my iMac has?

Comment: If you plan to upgrade either way (blade requires converter board + different type of SSD, while sata requires 3.5 to 2.5 bracket + sata SSD), why can't you just open the mac and take a look? Would you like to minimise downtime?

Comment: Yes I'd like to minimize downtime, and I'm hoping to avoid being the one to open up my iMac since it's a difficult and delicate procedure and I have butter fingers.

Comment: does this help? https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/iMac+27-Inch+2017+Blade+SSD+Replacement/136963

Comment: @SteveChambers Yes that makes it clear I have a blade SSD. If you want to submit an excerpt from that as an answer I can mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best guide to 'what SSD is in my Mac is here:

https://beetstech.com/blog/apple-proprietary-ssd-ultimate-guide-to-specs-and-upgrades

However, it doesn't say anything about the 2017 iMac. What it does show is that Apple used its proprietary 12+16 pin module from "Generation 3" (mid-2013) until the introduction of on-board SSD modules.

So if your SSD is replaceable, it will almost certainly be a 12+16 pin blade.

It may be possible to glean some information from the System Information.app.

TBH, you'd probably be just as well served by a fast external drive connected via Thunderbolt.

Comment: @BriBri Yes, in fact, i use a usb nvme drive. It boots up really fast. Furthermore, this prevents issues such as this: https://tinyapps.org/blog/202110270700_monterey-third-party-ssd.html